# Resampling of Weather Data for variable timeperiods by using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, circular-dependency

Ive been trying to create a generic weather importer that can resample data to set intervals (e.g. from 20min to hours or the like (I've use 60min in the code below)).
For this I wanted to use the Pandas resample function. After a bit of puzzling I came up with the below (which is not the prettiest code). I had one problem with the averaging of the wind direction for the set periods, which I've tried to solve with pandas' resampler.apply.

However, I've hit a problem with the definition which gives the following **error:
TypeError: can't convert complex to float**

I realise I'm trying to force a square peg in a round hole, but I have no idea how to overcome this. Any hints would be appreciated.

[raw data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rxEwy8CoVEhs5rW27xCsVXnAZ3CWU2eo/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from math import *

os.chdir('C:\\test')
file = 'bom.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=0, low_memory=False)

#custom dataframe reampler (.resampler.apply) 
def custom_resampler(thetalist):
    try:
        s=0
        c=0
        n=0.0
        for theta in thetalist:
            s=s+sin(radians(theta))
            c=c+cos(radians(theta))
            n+=1
        s=s/n
        c=c/n
        eps=(1-(s**2+c**2))**0.5
        sigma=asin(eps)*(1+(2.0/3.0**0.5-1)*eps**3)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        sigma=0
    return degrees(sigma)

# create time index and format dataframes
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df.index = df['DateTime']
df = df.drop(['Year','Month', 'Date', 'Hour', 'Minutes','DateTime'], axis=1)
dfws = df
dfwdd = df
dfws = dfws.drop(['WDD'], axis=1)
dfwdd = dfwdd.drop(['WS'], axis=1)

#resample data to xxmin and merge data
dfwdd = dfwdd.resample('60T').apply(custom_resampler)
dfws = dfws.resample('60T').mean()
dfoutput = pd.merge(dfws, dfwdd, right_index=True, left_index=True)

# write series to Excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('bom_out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
dfoutput.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bom_out')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you try pandas Grouper ? [pandas.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: Hi @IbraheemAyoup, Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately grouper cannot be used for this since I cant apply a definition to it to calculate the circular average. The problem I have has more todo with the definition. Again, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bit more research and found that changing the definition worked best.
However, this gave a weird outcome by opposing angle (180degrees) division, which I accidently discovered. I had to deduct a small value, which will give a degree error in the actual outcome.

I would still be interested to know:

1. what was done wrong with the complex math
2. a better solution for opposing angles (180 degrees)

```
# changed the imports
from math import sin,cos,atan2,pi
import numpy as np

#changed the definition
def custom_resampler(angles,weights=0,setting='degrees'):
    '''computes the mean angle'''
    if weights==0:
         weights=np.ones(len(angles))
    sumsin=0
    sumcos=0
    if setting=='degrees':
        angles=np.array(angles)*pi/180
    for i in range(len(angles)):
        sumsin+=weights[i]/sum(weights)*sin(angles[i])
        sumcos+=weights[i]/sum(weights)*cos(angles[i])
    average=atan2(sumsin,sumcos)
    if setting=='degrees':
        average=average*180/pi
        if average == 180 or average == -180: #added since 290 degrees and 110degrees average gave a weird outcome
            average -= 0.1
        elif average < 0:
            average += 360
    return round(average,1)
```